# ReactJS - link to doesn't work for URL with parameter

Tags: reactjs

I use ReactJS and react-router-dom (version 4.2). I can't have my links working with :

```
<Link to={'/site/' + site.id}>
    <h5><Icon name="map-marker"/> {site.title}</h5>
</Link>
```

It works when I am on home page (http://localhost:3000), the component is rendered, but when I am on a page like : http://localhost:3000/site/1, I can't go to URL http://localhost:3000/site/2.

The URL changes in address bar, but nothing happens.

I use :

```
...
<Route path="/site/:id" render={(props) => (
    <SitesView id={props.match.params.id} />
)}/>
...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, undefined, { pure: false })(App);
```

In my Router. I can't get it, is it because the URL are almost the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood , you have one component `<SitesView/>` for all of the `/site/` routes with different `props.id`'s.

When you change the parameter of URL, the id of `<SitesView/>` component and the URL will be changed but be noticed **the `<SitesView/>` is rendered on previous route** and at the moment you are seeing this rendered component which has no knowledge aboute the changes.

Then you need to use one of the [React LifeCycle Methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) named **[componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp, nextState)](https://www.lynda.com/React-js-tutorials/componentWillReceiveProps/592509/646166-4.html)** to get to know **when the id of `<SitesView/>` changed**. and based on new id you can update your component.

Comment: Ok thanks for this explanation, for now I will just use `<a href="site/2"` which re-render the page, and very more simple. I will try your method when I will have time

Comment: Ok but it's better to find a solution for this problem like componentWillReceiveProps sooner because using re-render for update sth is the violation of SPA.

Comment: I know it, but I need a lot to make it work, but I will use it. I found other informations on StackOverflow since you explained me.